# array_unshift, force second value

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to build a table of content in .json for an interactive book. My output has to start with:

```
{
  "url": "index.html",
  "hidden": true
},
```

but after that I would like to add arrays. The array_unshift adds an element *before* this value and I would like the script to add new arrays *after* it instead. In other words the *index.html* should stay at top and be succeeded by the arrays I generate with my script. How do I do this?

*post.php*

```
<?php
// check if a form was submitted
if( !empty( $_POST ) ){

    $file = 'entries.json';

    $json = file_get_contents($file);

    // convert json back to a php stdClass
    $phpClass = json_decode($json);

    $postArray = array(
         "url" => $_POST['url'],
         "title" => $_POST['title'],
         "thumb" => $_POST['thumb'],
         "byline" => $_POST['byline']
    );

     // push the new $postArray onto the top of phpClass
     array_unshift($phpClass->contents, $postArray);

     // encode php class into json again
     $new_json = json_encode($phpClass);

     // write it out
     file_put_contents( $file, $new_json);
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just wait until the array is built, then unshift the first element into place?

Comment: What should this script look like? @TecBrat

Answer (score 0):

Look at a little example:

```
//example array
$array = array('a', 'b');

//position, where we want to paste new value
$offset = 2;

$result = array_slice($array, 0, $offset - 1, true) +
    array("my_key" => "my_value") +
    array_slice($array, $offset - 1, count($array)- $offset + 1, true);
```

And now if we call `var_dump()` on our `$result` we will get:

```
array
  0 => string 'a' (length=1)
  'my_key' => string 'my_value' (length=8)
  1 => string 'b' (length=1)
```

Instead of `array("my_key" => "my_value")` in the example You can use Your own array. And it will be always the second in the resulting one.

Comment: That I have. But is it possible to use `array_push()` to put the array as the second item in an array? I thought that this would place it at the bottom.

Comment: @user3607657, it pushes new elements to the end of Your array and keeps the first element first, as You need. Or Your problem is slightly different?

Comment: Yes, my problem is that i want my new object to be placed as the _second_ in my array. Not on top or bottom.

Comment: @user3607657, I've edited the answer above, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

**NOT TESTED**

```
$file = 'entries.json';

$json = file_get_contents($file);

// convert json back to a php stdClass
$phpClass = json_decode($json);

// cut the header off
$header=array_shift($phpClass);

$postArray = array(
     "url" => $_POST['url'],
     "title" => $_POST['title'],
     "thumb" => $_POST['thumb'],
     "byline" => $_POST['byline']
);

 // push the new $postArray onto the top of phpClass
 array_unshift($phpClass->contents, $postArray);

 // paste the header back on.
 array_unshift($phpClass->contents, $header);

 // encode php class into json again
 $new_json = json_encode($phpClass);

 // write it out
 file_put_contents( $file, $new_json);
```

}